# Check file name and filter it based on the date

Tags: linux, shell-script, perl

I have many files one of my scripts generate daily. The file name structure resembles:

capacity_data_2012-12-02.txt , capacity_data_2012-12-03.txt and so on...

I want to create a script which would check for the last month of data. For example today is capacity_data_2012-12-28.txt.  I'd create a list of the files for the last 30 days. Any files more than 30 days old (not in my list) would then be moved to another directory.

Any direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move files older than 30 days, or more precisely, files which as not been written in the last 30 days:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "capacity_data_???-??-??.txt" -mtime +30 -exec echo mv {} another_directory/ \;
```

(Remove the `echo` when you are happy with the output.)

If you want to list the files of the last 30 days:

```
awk 'BEGIN{now_n = systime() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;
           for(n = 30; n >= 0; n--) {
             print "capacity_data_" strftime("%Y-%m-%d", now_n) ".txt"
             now_n += 24* 60 * 60;
           }}'
```

And if you want to loop on those files:

```
files=$(awk 'BEGIN{now_n = systime() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60;
                   for(n = 30; n >= 0; n--) {
                     print "capacity_data_" strftime("%Y-%m-%d", now_n) ".txt"
                     now_n += 24* 60 * 60;
                    }}')
for file in $files; do
  echo $file
done
```